# Какие требования для установки docker на linux

Tags: linux, docker

Подскажите, какие минимальные системные требования для установки docker на linux (debian-образный)? Для Windows desktop везде указано, что минимум 4ГБ, х64-процессор, Win10, а для линукса что-то не могу найти.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/binaries/#install-daemon-and-client-binaries-on-linux

Comment: Это я видел. Но нигде не могу найти минимальный объем оперативной памяти.

Comment: ну раз памяти хватает для работы linux , то для docker точно хватит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если имеются ввиду аппаратные(hardware) требования, то docker сам по себе не обладает минимальными аппаратными требованиями. Это лишь утилита для виртуализации. Всё зависит от масштаба приложений которые будут развёрнуты внутри контейнеров.
Аппаратное требование только одно - поддержка этой самой виртуализации.
Что касается системных(software) требований, то от системы на базе ОС linux требуется только:

1. Битность 64
2. Ядро не старее 3.10

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Почему задал вопрос, т.к. на windows'е он у меня отказался ставиться при оперативке в 3 ГБ. Поэтому и непонятно, будет ли смысл ставить линукс и на него уже докер.